# How to write private variable string in console

Tags: c#, console, console.writeline

I need to declare a private variable that should not be available to any derived classes, outside classes or programs.

So I did this but I don't know if it's correct to start off with:

```
class Program
{
    public const int width = 100;
    public const int height = 30;
    protected int gameCharX;
    protected int gameCharY;
    private string clea = "C";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("" + clea);
        Console.SetWindowSize(width, height);              
        Console.ReadLine();
    }        
}
```

It also gives me the error in the writeline:

Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: `new Program().clea`

Comment: you are trying to access a non static variable from a static method. Either you should make clea variable as static or create a new instance of Program class and access clea variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because your variable clea is not accessible in main. 
Why not accessible? Because it's (Program) not a static class where you can access class properties(clea) without instantiation. Hence, you can create an instance on the go like below

```
  Console.WriteLine("" + new Program(). clea);
```

Or

Make the private method as static

```
`private static string clea = "C"`;
```

And access it as usual

```
Console.WriteLine("" + clea);
```